# Prediction the sign of returns in R by svm

Tags: r, svm, prediction

I tried to predict a sign of returns by SVM, but have a mistake somewhere because result is poor.

```
x <- sign(dataset)
trainindex1= x[1:5792,1]
trainindex2 = x[1:5792,-1]
testindex = x[5792:7030,-1]
trainindex1 <- as.factor(trainindex1)
trainindex2 <- as.vector(trainindex2)
testindex <- as.vector(testindex)
svmFit = svm (y=trainindex1, x=trainindex2,
              type="C",
              kernel= "radial",
              gamma=5,
              cost=30)
predsvm = predict(svmFit, testindex)
table(predsvm, testindex)
```

result

```
       testindex
predsvm   -1    0    1
     -1    0    0    0
     0     0    0    0
     1  2819    5 3371
```

Please, can you help me and explain me how could I fix it?

Comment: What does your training data look like? What does `predsvm` return? How balanced is your training data? Is your test sample representative? How did you choose your hyper parameters and kernel?

Comment: training data is just signs of financial returns from 1990 to 2013.
I have real signs from 2013 to 2017 and would like to compare them.
I tried different kernels and parameters and nothing changes. I suppose that something should be fixed before I will change parameters and kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am not sure which of your variables are supposed to be classes and which numbers. I assume TARGET is a factor and all the rest are numbers. In this case you could try the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- sign(dataset)%>%as.data.frame
x$TARGET<-as.factor(as.character(x$TARGET))
trainindex= x[1:5792,]
testindex = x[5793:7030,]
svmFit = svm (TARGET~.,data=trainindex,type="C",kernel= "radial",gamma=5,cost=30)
predsvm = predict(svmFit, newdata=testindex)
confusionMatrix(predsvm, testindex$TARGET)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can go further and tune model and may be avoid zero sign.